# Creating variable alias in java

Tags: java, variables

I need a way to write `R1` or `R[1]` and refer to the same variable.

Comment: Without more context: `Object R1 = R[1];`

Comment: And what do you need this for?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to use the general pattern of having ALPHANUMBER and ALPHA[NUMBER] refer to the same variable, you can't do it. The square bracket notation in Java refers to an element in an array, while the first is just a general identifier that can refer to a variable.

In the specific case of creating two variables, one a direct reference and the other an element in an array, you can simply point `r[1] = r1` (as long as `r1` has been initialized).